# Updating existing records with IDs of new rows while using a "with" clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Platform: Ruby on Rails with PostgreSQL database.

Problem:
We are doing some backfilling to migrate our data to a new structure. It's created a rather convoluted situation, and we'd like to handle it as efficiently as possible. It's partially addressed with SQL similar to this:

```
with rows as (
  insert into responses (prompt_id, answer, received_at, user_id, category_id)
  select prompt_id, null as answer, received_at, user_id, category_id
  from prompts
  where user_status = 0 and skipped is not true
  returning id, category_id
)
insert into category_responses (category_id, response_id)
select category_id, id as response_id
from rows;
```

The tables and columns have been obfuscated/simplified so the reasoning behind it may not be as clear, but category_responses is a many-to-many join table. What we're doing is grabbing existing prompts, and creating a set of empty responses (answer is NULL) for each.

The piece that's missing is to then associate the records in **prompts** with the newly created **responses**. Is there a way to do this within the query? I would like to avoid adding a prompt_id column to answers if possible, but I am guessing this would be one way to handle that, including it in the `returning` clause, then issuing a second query to update the prompts table - and anyway I'm not even sure you can run more than one query with the results of a single `with` clause.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have settled on adding the needed column, and updated the query as follows:

```sql
with tab1 as (
  insert into responses (prompt_id, answer, received_at, user_id, category_id, prompt_id)
  select prompt_id, null as answer, received_at, user_id, category_id
  from prompts
  where user_status = 0 and skipped is not true
  returning id, category_id, prompt_id
),
tab2 as (
  update prompts
  set response_id = tab1.response_id,
  category_id = tab1.category_id
  from tab1
  where prompts.id = tab1.prompt_id
  returning prompts.response_id as response_id, prompts.category_id as category_id
)
insert into category_responses (category_id, response_id)
select category_id, id as response_id
from tab2;
```